# ClojureScript Setup from book

Tags: clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

I am following the learning ClojurScript book from Packt, and I am a little lost on something. I have a project.clj file with the following configuration

```
(defproject piggieback_project "0.5.2" 
  :description "FIXME: write description" 
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME" 
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License" 
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"} 
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.3"]
              [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.879"]
                [weasel "0.7.1" :exclusions
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript]]] 
 :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[cider/piggieback "0.5.2"]
                                [org.clojure/tools.nrepl"0.2.10"]]
                 :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cider.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}}})
```

I am able to run lein repl
and get a repl

I then run the following with this result

```
Clojure 1.10.3
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_302-b08
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=> (require 'cljs.build.api)
nil
user=> (cljs.build.api/build "src"
  #_=> {:main 'piggieback-project.core
  #_=> :output-to "out/main.js"
  #_=>  :verbose true})
Options passed to ClojureScript compiler: {:output-dir "out", :closure-warnings {:check-types :off, :check-variables :off}, :closure-defines {}, :ups-libs nil, :cache-analysis true, :closure-module-roots [], :optimizations :none, :ups-foreign-libs [], :verbose true, :aot-cache false, :preloads [process.env], :ignore-js-module-exts [".css"], :output-to "out/main.js", :preamble ["cljs/imul.js"], :ups-externs nil, :opts-cache "cljsc_opts.edn", :source-map true, :cache-analysis-format :transit, :main piggieback-project.core, :language-in :es6, :emit-constants nil}
Unexpected error compiling at (REPL:1).
Could not write JavaScript nil

user=> (require 'weasel.repl.websocket)

user=> (cider.piggieback/cljs-repl
  #_=> (weasel.repl.websocket/repl-env :ip "0.0.0.0" :port
  #_=>       9001))
<< started Weasel server on ws://0.0.0.0:9001 >>
<< waiting for client to connect ...
```

This is correct according to the book as to my result. But The next step is to open up my html file at the root which looks like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="out/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in my src directory I have a core.clj file with the following

```
(ns piggieback-project.core 
  (:require [weasel.repl :as repl])) 
(when-not (repl/alive?) 
  (repl/connect "ws://localhost:9001"))
```

When I open the html file it's supposed to connect to the weasel websocket server and give me a user repl but it does not.

I am brand new to Clojurscript, So any help here at all would be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core.clj file should be named core.cljs!  (Full path from the project root: `src/piggieback_project/core.cljs`.)

P.S. Remove the incomplete "out" directory before you try again, to give the compiler a fresh start.